# From inside a perl script can you know the name of the file you are redirecting output to?

Tags: perl

So I have:

```
test.pl > test.log
```

is there a way to know inside test.pl that I am outputing to 'test.log'? At the end of my script I want to do some manipulation of test.log without hardcoding the name.

Comment: I'm afraid you can't know.

Comment: Consider writing a separate script to do the post-output manipulation, e.g. `test.pl | postprocess > test.log`, or `test.pl > test.log && postprocess test.log`.

Comment: @Aaron Miller, That doesn't work if a script accepts a variable number of input, in which case `-o` is traditionally used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can redirect standard output from perl, with minimal changes to your script,

```
test.pl test.log
```

---

```
my ($file) = @ARGV;
if (@ARGV) {
  open STDOUT, ">", $file or die $!;
}

print "output is redirected to $file\n";

# use $file at the end
```

Comment: Is there any need to close STDOUT at the end? is it a good practice to?

Comment: @Bill no need to do that

Comment: Should be `if (@ARGV) { ($file) = @ARGV; ... }`, else I can't use a file named `0` (zero).

Comment: @amon perhaps `length($file)` as $file can also be empty string `perl -E 'say 44 if @ARGV' ""`

Comment: `my ($file) = @ARGV;` squashes all of `@ARGV` into a single string, which is probably not what you meant. You might also want to be able to optionally output to stdout, as e.g. most of the GNU coreutils. You could say `my ($file) = $ARGV[0] || undef` and then later `my $fh; if ($file) { open $fh, ... } else { $fh = *STDOUT }`, and from there on print to the `$fh` filehandle and have output go wherever it's supposed to.

Comment: @AaronMiller that would require quite a bit of changes to the original script. `my ($file) = @ARGV;` doesn't squash anything.

Comment: @mpapec Oh, I see, the parentheses around `$file` make it a list-to-list assignment, so it just takes element 0. Why not just `my $file = $ARGV[0]` instead, and stop giving people more reasons to hate Perl than they already have? I've been using the language for going on twenty years now, and I still had to write up that construct and test it in order to know accurately what it would do.

Comment: @AaronMiller that is actually common idiom in perl, ie. in subroutine `my ($p1, $p2) = @_;`

Comment: @mpapec I am very well aware of the idiom. My point is that using it to take a single value off the top of an array is, while correct in the sense that it does what you want, broken in the sense that it unnecessarily obfuscates your meaning. The primary reason why people hate Perl is because TIMTOWTDI lends itself far too easily to this sort of thing; while it's probably too late to rehabilitate Perl's image among programmers in general, it certainly makes life easier for other Perl hackers to restrain yourself to common idioms, preferably those in the Perl Cookbook, where possible.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe. The following works on Linux, but will not be very portable to other systems...

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $out = readlink("/proc/$$/fd/1");
print STDERR "I am being output to $out\n";
```

Naturally, this is probably a bad idea. Better to explicitly open the file and write to it in Perl, rather than having the shell set up redirections.

Comment: You can also have the script output to a file if it gets a filename argument and otherwise output to stdout; this way, both `test.pl test.log` and `test.pl > test.log` will behave as intended, although of course in the latter case the script won't be able to know where its output is going. (But that's only arguably among test.pl's legitimate concerns in any case.)